# How do you run a command after some playsound music?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a map, and, to put it simply, I need to run a command when some music finishes (played via a playsound command), and my only solution at the moment is a huge room full of repeaters making a delay as long as the music, with the command block at the end, which *would* work, but, for obvious reasons, I don't really want to do that. Can anyone help? If you have any more questions, ask in the comments, and I'll try and get back to you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this question essentially how to efficiently create a long delay?

Comment: @colorfusion Pretty much, yeah.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an structure like that:
[image]

And when music start to sound execute /time set command substracting 20 to 22340 by each seconds you want to delay the command.

**For example:**

- If music duration is **10 seconds** you must delay the command by 10 seconds
  so:

  22340-(10*20) = **22140**

  **So you must execute `/time set 22140` when music starts sound**
- If music duration is **17 seconds** you must delay the command by 17 seconds so:

  22340-(17*20) = **22000**

  **So you must execute `/time set 22000` when music starts to sound**

I hope I've explained that clearly

Comment: This is a good answer and I see how it works, but I don't really want to change the time on my map (Most of my map is outside). This solution would also run the command every time it turned day, which would get annoying. Thanks for the response, though, it is appreciated, but not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Ultimatro You could make your own dummy objective that works like the time.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a dispenser with arrows in it pointing towards a wooden button and when the music starts trigger the dispenser. The arrow will despawn in 60 seconds (1 minute). For example, (I did this very same contraption) I played records.11 and triggered the dispenser, shot one arrow, and afterward I had a line of repeaters (4 tick) that triggered a tp command in the end.